# HERE geocoding API - Storing location geocodes in local DB

Tags: here-api, geocoder

Would like to understand which Pricing option will support storing the Geocodes in local DB and Bulk geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the Terms and Conditions on Here data here - https://developer.here.com/terms-and-conditions#restrictions-on-here-materials.

Caching or storing any location data for the purpose of building a repository of location assets or scaling one request to serve multiple end users is prohibited. Customer may not use any HERE Services in a manner that pre-fetches, caches, or stores data or results, except:

As explicitly allowed by the caching headers (HTTP/1.1 standard) returned by HERE Services; or
To the extent Customer is storing or caching for no more than thirty (30) days only to the extent necessary for enabling or improving an end user's use of the HERE Services.

For more details you can contact Here Help via https://developer.here.com/help.